# Xamarin.Forms: Parse array value from response and show it in the UI

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a response like below:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "errorDetails": [
        "An Error Occured During Registration"
    ],
    "userId": 0,
    "schoolId": 0,
    "planAmount": 0,
    "discountId": 0,
    "userProfileId": 0
}
```

I need to show the errorDetails content to UI if the status value is false. errorDetails is an array, so what was the type that I can use in the front end and how I can parse that value?

**I tried like below:**

```
public class SignUpResponse
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public string userProfileId { get; set; }
    public List<string> errorDetails { get; set; }
}

string error = "";
if (signUpdetails.errorDetails.Count > 0)
{
    error = signUpdetails.errorDetails[0];
}
if (!status)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", error.ToString(), "OK");
}
```

But this is not working, nothing is showing in the alert?

Comment: My mistake, in my test scenario errordetails was empty. My code is working fine. Sorry guys for the foolish question.
Hope this thread will help someone for parsing array value from the response and show it in UI. So I am not deleting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a JSON response, is it being read into the object correctly? IE: there are errorDetails present in the object when you test?

Please confirm that both the overall object and the errorDetails are populated and not empty or null.

Comment: My mistake, errordetails was empty. .ToString() is not a problem. So can you edit your answer accordingly? Or should I delete this post?

Comment: I will edit my response, can you edit your question to validate that the object is empty and include the code you use to populate the model from the JSON please?

Comment: I think my question is ok, you just edit the answer as please confirm your errordetails is empty or not? When you do that I will accept the answer.